# Make Git Global/System Configuration readonly

Tags: git, ssl, github

'Git Config' can set configurations in multiple levels as mentioned below:

- Repository Configuration
- Global Configuration
- System Level Configuration.

Repository configuration overwrites Global. Global overwrites System configuration.

**Question #1:** How Can I make sure the Repository Configuration not overwritting the Global Configuration? For instance,

Command 1: git config --global http.sslVerify 'true'

Command 2: git config http.sslVerify 'false'

Command 2 will be overriding the secure configuration (ie. Always do SSL Verification) set on Global Configuration. Command 2 will stop the SSL Verification.  I want to make sure all git repositories does have secure configuration and not have the ability to override it. Is it possible to do it?

**Question #2**: Git users also have the ability to override the global configuration by using commandline options as mentioned below. Is it possible to block this as well?

Command: git -c http.sslVerify=false clone https://domain.com/path/to/git

Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: It's not possible unless you want to use your own custom version of the `git` binary(ies)

Comment: That's what I thought.. I just want to throw this to the community to see if its possible :). Thanks for getting back to me :)